# Differentiating a uid-wide kill(-1,…) from a targetted kill

Tags: c, posix, system-calls, kill

If a process runs `kill(-1,SIGKILL);` (or with a different signal) and the call kills the caller (MacOS's  `kill(-1,...)` does that, though Linux's leaves the caller alive) but not its parent (the parent has a different uid), can the parent, using facilities provided by POSIX, tell if the kill-caller died because it killed itself with the `kill(-1,...)` call or because another process killed it?

Comment: Signals don't carry any information about their source, so no, you can't distinguish those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you send `SIGKILL` to the process(es), they'll never see the signal - they're just summarily killed by the kernel.

Otherwise, per [**2.4.3 Signal Actions** of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03), you can extract the PID of the process that sent the signal if your signal handler is registered with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag:

> If the `SA_SIGINFO` flag for the signal is set, the signal-catching
>   function shall be entered as a C-language function call as follows:
>
> ```
> void func(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);
> ```
>
> where `func` is the specified signal-catching function, `signo` is the
>   signal number of the signal being delivered, and `info` is a pointer
>   to a `siginfo_t` structure defined in `<signal.h>` containing at least
>   the following members:
>
> ```
> Member Type    Member Name   Description
> int            si_signo      Signal number.
> int            si_code       Cause of the signal.
> pid_t          si_pid        Sending process ID.
> uid_t          si_uid        Real user ID of sending process.
> void *         si_addr       Address of faulting instruction.
> int            si_status     Exit value or signal.
> union sigval   si_value      Signal value.
> ```
>
> The `si_signo` member shall contain the signal number. This shall be
>   the same as the `signo` parameter. The `si_code` member shall contain
>   a code identifying the cause of the signal. The following
>   non-signal-specific values are defined for `si_code`:
>
> `SI_USER`
>       The signal was sent by the `kill()` function. The implementation may set `si_code` to `SI_USER` if the signal was sent by the `raise()`
>   or `abort()` functions or any similar functions provided as
>   implementation extensions. `SI_QUEUE`
>       The signal was sent by the `sigqueue()` function. `SI_TIMER`
>       The signal was generated by the expiration of a timer set by `timer_settime()`. `SI_ASYNCIO`
>       The signal was generated by the completion of an asynchronous I/O request. `SI_MESGQ`
>       The signal was generated by the arrival of a message on an empty message queue.
>
> Signal-specific values for `si_code` are also defined, as described in
>   `<signal.h>`.

That should provide enough information to tell if the signal was generated by a call to `kill()`, what process sent the signal, who sent the signal.  Or if the signal was generated by an internal fault such as with a `SIGSEGV`.